# How to grant permission to a user in Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm a newbie on SQL, I'd like to know how to grant select and other permissions  to a specify user in Azure Sql Server.

I'm trying to use [AUMC](http://AUMC.codeplex.com/) to do this, I've created a new login as well as a new user `test` and grant all permissions I can select on [AUMC](http://AUMC.codeplex.com/). (for master database, I've assigned roles `loginmanager` and `dbmanager` to `test`, for other database, I've assigned permissions `db_owner`, `db_securityadmin`, `db_accessadmin`, `db_backupoperator`, `db_ddladmin`, `db_datawriter`, `db_datareader`, `db_denydatawriter`, `db_denydatareader` to `test`).

After the setting, I'm trying to login to the Azure SQL Server via ssms. The login is success, but I cannot find any tables on the database except the `System Tables`.
And when I execute `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <a_table>`, it returns **The `SELECT` permission was denied on the object `<a_table>`, database `<the database>`, schema `dbo`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are adding your `test` user to the `db_denydatawriter` and `db_denydatareader` roles. These roles **prevent** the user from reading or writing in the database, overriding the permissions granted by other roles like `db_datawriter` and `db_datareader`. Try removing your user from these two 'deny' roles.

For more information on the various database-level roles, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx